# Join rows based on particular column value in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains 2 columns, Class and Name. Here is an example of the data:

```
    Class       Name
    Physics     Anna
    Physics     Bob
    Maths       Gary
    Biology     Anna
    Biology     Gary
```

I am trying to join the 'Name' column based on the 'Class' column. The output I am looking for should be:

```
    Class       Name
    Physics     Anna Bob
    Maths       Gary
    Biology     Anna Gary
```

Note, no commas between the names. This is because I will be feeding this output to another system which requires the output to be in this format. Seeking assistance!

Thanks for reading!

Comment: `df.goupby('Class')['Name'].agg(' '.join)`

Comment: @Erfan: Thanks! This is almost what I am looking for. However, this code creates just one column with Class and aggregated Names. Is it possible to make it two columns, Class and Names with names joined ?

Comment: `df.groupby('Class', as_index=False).agg(' '.join)` or `df.goupby('Class')['Name'].agg(' '.join).reset_index()`

Comment: This works. Thanks again @Erfan!